# getting error with chromedriver using RemoteWebdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid2

Getting error:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver
>   executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
>   for more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

My code :

```
capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
capability.setVersion("38.0.2125.122 m");
String strChromePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
    + "\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", strChromePath);
capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.77:5555/wd/hub"),
        capability);
```

On the above code chromedriver it self is not getting invoked.

Then i tried with code:

```
ChromeDriverService chromeService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("webdrivers/chromedriver.exe"))
            .usingAnyFreePort().build();
chromeService.start();
capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
capability.setVersion("38.0.2125.122 m");
capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.77:5555/wd/hub"),
        capability);
```

On executing above code the executable is launched but chrome is not invoked. It throws the same error. Code is working fine for firefox. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the relevant Chrome driver as per your system(32-bit/64-bit), [from here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.11/) . Try setting the property of ChromeDriver first, like this:

```
File file = new File("D:\\chromedriver.exe"); //path to the chromedriver.exe so downloaded
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then use this code:-

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
capability.setVersion("38.0.2125.122 m");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.77:5555/wd/hub"),capability);
```

---

If there is no need of using **"RemoteWebDriver"**, you can code just use this below :

```
File file = new File("D:\\chromedriver.exe"); //path to the chromedriver.exe so downloaded
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Still the same issue. I am first time using remote webdriver, so i guess i am doing it the proper way. The steps i followed are - 
Start the hub
Start the node and then execute the test.

Comment: Hope this link helps. http://blog.varunin.com/2011/10/running-tests-on-google-chrome-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
    WebDriver driver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "properties/chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

Put chrome driver in properties folder.